# Wpf window or usercontrol add property

Tags: wpf

Можно ли добавить свое свойство в окно или пользовательский элемент в XAMLе по мимо элементов типа texbox и т.п.

Comment: Да, конечно.

Расскажите, что именно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Ы? А где должен находиться `Expander`? И где должно находиться свойство? В вашем `UserControl`е? (Что ж из вас информацию вытягивать приходится?)

Comment: Вот XAML.
   <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <Expander
               <Button x:Name="btn">
            </Expander>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TreeView x:Name="trvMy"/>
    </Grid>

Comment: Если пытаться присоединится к элементу по типу ElementName=LayoutRoot то только из тега расположенного в Window.Resources а обратится к TreeView нет возможности его не видно. По этому нужно что-то что есть в ресурсе например свойство <Button  x:Name="btn">. И как же объявить свойство?
Если контрол в теге <Expander /> то свойство должно быть типа <Мое свойство />

Comment: В ресурсе окна указываю DataTemplate как формировать в TreeView новый Item в зависимости от типа класса, здесь же нужно указать поведение при выборе CurrentItem. Из ресурсов обратится к отображаемому TreeView не могу, по этому есть мысль в ресурсе окна XAML объявить свойство, значение которого будет изменятся императивно и которое будет привязано в DataTemplate.

Comment: @radiknrg: То есть, вы хотите _одно_ свойство чтобы отвечало за _все_ элементы TreeView?

Comment: Если Item выбран, то вывод подробностей, у остальных Item скрытие подробностей

Comment: @radiknrg: обновил ответ

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, так: объявляете `UserControl`:

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.YourClass" xmlns...
             x:Name="ControlRoot">
    ...
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=ControlRoot}">
       ...
    </Expander>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

xaml.cs:

```
public partial class YourClass
{
    public YourClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region dependency property bool IsExpanded
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(YourClass),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));
    #endregion
}
```

И пользуетесь:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type job:Draft}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkList, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <code:YourClass IsExpanded="{Binding ...}">
```

Или можно, по идее, напрямую, без `UserControl`'а:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type job:Draft}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkList, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ...}">
```

(тут уж как в вашем коде правильнее, вы архитектор, вам решать).

---

Конкретно для вашей задачи, почему бы не сделать так:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Ну или `IsSelected` вместо `IsFocused`.